# Simplify integral considering only the real part

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

I happened to stumble on the following simplification of an integral:

$$ \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \ e^{-ax}  \cdot \cos(kx) = \frac{1}{\pi} Re \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \ e^{x (ik - a)}  \right]   $$

According to my reasoning: $ \cos(kx) = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{ikx} + e^{-ikx}  \right)  $, so the term on the exponent on the right side comes somehow from the first term of the complex form of $\cos(kx)$, but the second term gets cancelled, why?

Answer (score 1):

Consider first $e^{ikx} = \cos(kx) + i \sin(kx)$ then you can easily deduce that 
$$
Re(e^{ikx}) = \cos(kx).
$$